# Leaflet Marker Cluster coverage path options

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

How do I override the options for the Leaflet.markercluster coverage path?

It is using the default style.(The blue shape when the yellow marker cluster button is being hovered).

Or is there a way to disable it on mouseover?

[image: path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the Leaflet.markercluster plugin, and are asking how to customize the coverage polygon that is displayed when hovering a cluster, or how to disable this feature?

In that case:

- to disable this feature, use the [`showCoverageOnHover`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#enabled-by-default-boolean-options) option:

```js
L.markerClusterGroup({
  showCoverageOnHover: false
});
```

- to customize the appearance of the coverage polygon, use the [`polygonOptions`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options) option, with an object containing appropriate [path style options](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path):

```js
L.markerClusterGroup({
  polygonOptions: {
    color: "red"
  }
});
```

Comment: You are awesome! I added:
`showCoverageOnHover: false` and it did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Also, thank you for editing my question title!

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for your nice feedback! ;-)